# colorscale does not change the scatter points color in plotly 3d scatterplot in R

Tags: r, plot, colors, 3d, plotly

I am learning to plot in r using plotly package. This chunk of code is provided on plotly website: [enter link description here](https://plotly.com/r/3d-scatter-plots/)  . I change `colorscale = c('#FFE1A1', '#683531')` to let say `colorscale = c('blue', 'red')`. shouldnt it change the scatter  points colors? what part of the code is then supposed to change the color of the points gradiently. I know I can set it to pallette names or like "Greens", but I dont know how to give a range of gradient colors between two.

also as far as I looked, plotly 3d points can not have a sphere effecct. just wondering if I can mix it with rgl package who has.

library(plotly)

```
fig <- plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~wt, y = ~hp, z = ~qsec,
               marker = list(color = ~mpg, colorscale = c('#FFE1A1', '#683531'), showscale = TRUE))
fig <- fig %>% add_markers()
fig <- fig %>% layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = 'Weight'),
                                   yaxis = list(title = 'Gross horsepower'),
                                   zaxis = list(title = '1/4 mile time')),
                      annotations = list(
                        x = 1.13,
                        y = 1.05,
                        text = 'Miles/(US) gallon',
                        xref = 'paper',
                        yref = 'paper',
                        showarrow = FALSE
                        ))
fig
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same issue today, you can create your scale into a list before using colorscale:

```
colorscale <- list(c(0, 1), c("blue", "red"))
# or
colorscale <- list(c(0, 1), c("#FFE1A1", "#683531"))
```

Full code

```
fig <- plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~wt, y = ~hp, z = ~qsec,
               marker = list(color = ~mpg, colorscale=list(c(0, 1), c("blue", "red")), showscale = TRUE))
fig <- fig %>% add_markers()
fig <- fig %>% layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = 'Weight'),
                                   yaxis = list(title = 'Gross horsepower'),
                                   zaxis = list(title = '1/4 mile time')),
                      annotations = list(
                        x = 1.13,
                        y = 1.05,
                        text = 'Miles/(US) gallon',
                        xref = 'paper',
                        yref = 'paper',
                        showarrow = FALSE
                      ))
fig
```

[image]

Comment: Cool! worked perfectly! any idea how to make the points like like sphere just to make a the whole plot look even more fancy :)?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by sphere since they already look like spheres to me :)  
You can have a look at "symbol" and "opacity" arguments if you are looking for fancy option

`plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~wt, y = ~hp, z = ~qsec,
               marker = list(size = 8, symbol="circle", color = ~mpg, colorscale=list(c(0, 1), c("#FFE1A1", "#683531")), showscale = TRUE), opacity = 0.5)`